# Android network access entry point

Tags: java, android, http, android-ndk, network-programming

In Android you have a long list of possible libraries to perform an HTTP request and I have looked at a few [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html), [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), [AndroidAsyncHttp](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

While some of them use subclasses of `java.net.URLConnection` and others `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`, I have failed to understand what is the main entry point Android offers to accessing the network, the point where application layer HTTP GET and POST methods are passed to the rest of the network stack.

It is not my goal to build my own client or stack of network protocols, but I would like to know if there is **a single point where all this implementations converge** before being passed to the lower TCP layers and if it exists where is it located (Android kernel, NDK, JNI, JVM, singleton Java core object)?

Comment: "I have failed to understand what is the main entry point Android offers to accessing the network, the point where application layer HTTP GET and POST methods are passed to the rest of the network stack" -- um, I suppose you mean [`Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html).

Comment: A plain Java `Socket` perhaps?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have the impression that apache libraries use classes just from the `org.apache.http` package and `java.net.Socket` will not be present in this http libraries

Comment: `Socket` is part of the framework classes in standard JDKs and in the Android SDK. It does not have to "be present in this http libraries". Note that all of the HTTP stacks that you listed are open source. You can read the source code to determine where and how they use `Socket`.

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe I am looking at the wrong part of the class hierarchy, but I could not find `java.net.Socket` (or a subclass), being used in `java.net.URLConnection`.

Comment: `URLConnection` is an `abstract` class. `Socket` work will be conducted in concrete classes.

Comment: If this is the entry point of all this HTTP libraries and since `Socket` is part of the Android SDK, then is there a way to actually gain access to the Input and Output Streams of a socket?

Comment: It seems the converge is outside the application boundary (all your classes, imported libraries,etc) at "SDK" level, is this correct?